# Dependency Injection how to query on client side?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, ninject

My software project is set up in the following way:

1. Database (this handles the database specific work, like for MySQL, SQL Server)
2. DataClass (this project maps all database tables/columns to POCO classes)
3. Infrastructure (handles the bindings between DataClass and database using Ninject)
4. Project itself (has dependency on `Infrastructure` and `DataClass` project)

The idea behind it, is that the end user can choose, which database server fits best.

In the `Database` project, I query my database, convert it into the POCO class and give the data back to the `Project`.

This works really fine so far. Because of the late binding possibility of Ninject, I can bind different database projects at runtime.

**BUT**: what I did not get anyhow is: as long as I can use static queries everything works like this:

On `Infrastructure` side I can write something like this:

```
Function GetCustomerWithId(Id as Long) as POCOCustomerClass
```

Now in the `Project`, I can query by id and I get back a POCO class from the `Database` project. But, how can I query complex situations in the `Project`?

For example on client side I want to use Linq:

```
Dim GetCustomers = From Query in POCOCustomerClass

If checkbox.Checked = True
    GetCustomers = GetCustomers.Where(Function(item) item.Age > 10)
End If
```

The only way I get it working, when I bring back all customers from database into the POCO class and filter on Project side. But this makes no sense, because the query should be done on Server side.

So, how can I use the expression tree of a POCO Class on database side and translate it to the corresponding Linq?

Thanks a lot for every tip

Comment: The project side has a connection string to the database that allows linq to function.  You need to dynamically change the connection string in the project.  It is probably in the configuration file in the project.

Comment: Hey jdweng
THX for trying to help, but your answer isn't helping anyway, because I try to use Dependency Injection. This means, that the connection (and the connection string) is on DataBase Layer side and I don't have any reference from this project to the BusinessLogic. Only the DataClass has a  reference and DataClass has no connection string.
THX a lot

Comment: A database is always a file.  You connect either directly to the file or you connect to a server and the server connects to the file.  I can't tell from your posting if the file is local or remote.  If it is local you should be able to find the file on your computer.   The Data class object must have a connection string or a command which contains the connection string.  Normally command has a connection object and the connection string is in the connection.